# Missing menu button on MasterDetailPage when assigning App.MainPage

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

I got a little App where I need to Swap from a `ContentPage` to a `MasterDetailsPage`.

`MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyContentPage());`

Now if the login succeed I want to change the Root to `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyMasterDetailpage());`.

The MasterDetailsPage is shown, but the Button in the Navigation bar is missing then.

If I just use

`Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MyMasterDetailpage());`

I dont even get an Navigationbar, with

`Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new MyMasterDetailpage()));`

The menu icon is missing again.

Anything I can do here?

**Update**

It seems that my problem is only on Android, didn't know that the `new NavigationPage(new MyDetailView)` hamburger only appears on android.

Comment: I hit same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @DonBox No I didn't. I've changed the way how and when the MasterDetailPage is displayed. My solution was to set `MainPage = new MyMasterDetailpage()` from the beginning and just put a modal `MyContentPage()` over it. If login succeed, i just pop the modal in code behind which shows the MasterDetailPage. The MasterDetail inside a NavoigationPage seems not to work and is not needed the way i do it now

Comment: Thanks! What I saw was if the app starts with `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyMasterDetailPage())`, it works, I can see the sliding menu button. But if app starts with a different MainPage and then I set it to `new NavigationPage(new MyMasterDetailPage())`, the sliding menu button is not visible. Menu is there because if I swipe it appears. Maybe it's just a UI refresh issue.  I'm even considering writing a MD from scratch, by having a `NavigationPage` and `ContentPage`s. The slider menu would be created dynamically inside the `ContentPage` page. Still thinking about this....

Comment: @Don Box  Have u got solution for this i have a same issue.?

Answer (score 1):

NavigationMenu appears in `MasterDetailPage` when the `Detail` page is a `NavigationPage`. So rather than pushing MasterDetailsPage to Navigation stack, you may set it as MainPage. And then within MasterDetailPage, you need to add DetailPage within a NavigationPage.
You can set the Icon for the menu with Icon property of `MasterPage`
Here is an example below,

```
public class DashboardPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    DetailPage detailPage; 
    MenuPage  masterPage;
    NavigationPage detailNavigationPage;

    public DashboardPage ()
    {
        detailPage = new DetailPage ();
        detailNavigationPage=new NavigationPage(detailPage); // Navigation Page as parent for Detail Page.
        Detail = detailNavigationPage; 

        masterPage= new MenuPage(){Icon="ic_settings.png"}; // ic_settings.png willbe rendered as Menu Icon.
        Master = masterPage;

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is, that the MasterDetail is not my root page.. the whole tree looks like `NavigationPage( contentPage -> contentPage -> MasterDetailPage )` if I set my MasterDetail as root from the beginning it works just fine

Comment: You need not add MasterDetailPage to NavigationPage. You can rather set the MasterDetailPage as root page from some other page like this Application.Current.MainPage= new MyMasterDetailPage();

Comment: I've already tried that, if i do what exactly you say, the whole Bar on top is missing and of course the menu burger

Comment: Can you share the snippets of MasterDetailPage and the Page before MasterDetailPage ?

Comment: [Thats my master detail from xamarin samples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/MasterDetailPageDemoPage.cs) and the snippets before are what you said just before. I've tried to set new MainPage, I've tried to PushAsync and everything else i can gueess

Comment: And if you try Application.Current.MainPage= new NavigationPage(new MyMasterDetailPage()); to change the root?

Comment: Thats what I've tried. I get an navigation bar but it's just blank, no burger or icon or anything. If I set it as root first before using another navigationpage, it works fine...

Comment: You are also setting the Icon right , in MasterPage?

Comment: @Sreeraj It's all in the git link i've posted

Comment: Ok. I checked that. This is how detailPage is set in that link. NamedColorPage detailPage = new NamedColorPage (true);
   this.Detail = detailPage;             Can you try changing it to NamedColorPage detailPage = new NamedColorPage (true);
   this.Detail = new NavigationPage(detailPage); and check if it works ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But the solution was to make different the process. You wants to load, initially, the login view and then you show the view of the MasterDetail. I solved this as follows:

When you start the application, I create the view of the MasterDetail and immediately show the login view as a dialog, if the login is successful simply close the dialog. The code would look something like this:

```
public App()
{
    DependencyService.Register<IMessageService, MessageService>();
    DependencyService.Register<INavigationService,NavigationService>();

    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterDetail());

    MercaFacil.App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new LoginView()));
}
```

When the login is successful simply called the `PopModalAsync()` method

Answer (score 0):

By setting the icon of your Master page you should get the image you supply as a button in the navigationbar.

Try someting like this in your MyMasterDetailpage

```
public class MyMasterDetailpage: MasterDetailPage
{
    public MyMasterDetailpage()
    {
        Detail = new NavigationPage (new Page());
        Master = new MenuPage () {
            Title = "Title",
            Icon = (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS) ? "hamburgermenuicon.png" : null
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should I add an Icon manually? If I would use my MasterDetailPage as root of Application, i would get an animated burger?!

Comment: Only on android you get the animated one on iOS not

Comment: Okay I see, didn't know that thanks. However my Problem is related to android then. If because I only get a blank navigationbar there if i reassign the Application.MainPage

Comment: Title is needed on android too as far as i know, else i get an exception

Comment: Look at how I set the detail page and set the root like this: Application.Current.MainPage= new MyMasterDetailPage();

Comment: Set your detail page like this: Detail = new NavigationPage(yourpage);

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing the MasterDetailPage using the PushModalAsync then navigation bar will not be shown as it will open the page as a Modal in fullscreen mode. 
If you push the page as :

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyMasterDetailPage());
```

then u will get a back button on the navigation bar clicking it will move you backward to the page before. So your hamburger icon will not be visible.

The option is to set your MasterDetailPage as your MainPage

```
App.Current.MainPage = new MyMasterDetailPage();
```

If you want your Page which was added before the MasterDetailPage you can override the OnBackPressed() method in your android activity and push your page in the navigation stack and Pop your current MasterDetailpage.