# Couldn't get basic Hamburger Master Detail view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

After looking at all the questions and forums, I'm still unable to get my Master Detail page with Hamburger icon. If i use this Master detail page as application start then I'm seeing the functionality working as expected. Please look at the code below

DashBoadCreator.xaml
`

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>

</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>

  </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
`

`public partial class DashBoadCreator : MasterDetailPage
{
DashboardMaster master;
DashboardDetail1 detil;
public DashBoadCreator()
{
InitializeComponent();
master = new DashboardMaster();
detil = new DashboardDetail1();

        Master = master;
        Master.Title = "this is a title";
        Master.Icon = "icon.png";
        Detail = new NavigationPage(detil);

    }

    // Event for Menu Item selection, here we are going to handle navigation based
    // on user selection in menu ListView

}`
DashboadMaster.xaml
`

<!-- 
         This StackLayout you can use for other
         data that you want to have in your menu drawer

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#e74c3c"
                 HeightRequest="75">

      <Label Text="Some Text title"
             FontSize="20"
             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
             TextColor="White"
             HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>         -->

<ListView x:Name="navigationDrawerList"
          RowHeight="60"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8"
          ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected">

  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>

        <!-- Main design for our menu items -->
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Orientation="Horizontal"
                     Padding="20,10,0,10"
                     Spacing="20">

          <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                 WidthRequest="40"
                 HeightRequest="40"
                 VerticalOptions="Center" />

          <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                 FontSize="Medium"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                 TextColor="Black"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
`
```

` public partial class DashboardMaster : ContentPage
{

```
public List<MasterPageItem> menuList { get; set; }

public DashboardMaster()
{
    Title = "samples";
    InitializeComponent();

    menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();

    // Creating our pages for menu navigation
    // Here you can define title for item, 
    // icon on the left side, and page that you want to open after selection
    var page1 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 1", Icon = "itemIcon1.png", TargetType = typeof(DashboardDetail1) };
    var page2 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 2", Icon = "itemIcon2.png", TargetType = typeof(DashboardDetail1) };
    var page3 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 3", Icon = "itemIcon3.png", TargetType = typeof(DashboardDetail1) };
    var page4 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 4", Icon = "itemIcon4.png", TargetType = typeof(DashboardDetail1) };
    var page5 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 5", Icon = "itemIcon5.png", TargetType = typeof(DashboardDetail1) };
    var page6 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 6", Icon = "itemIcon6.png", TargetType = typeof(DashboardDetail1) };
    var page7 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 7", Icon = "itemIcon7.png", TargetType = typeof(DashboardDetail1) };
    var page8 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 8", Icon = "itemIcon8.png", TargetType = typeof(DashboardDetail1) };
    var page9 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Item 9", Icon = "itemIcon9.png", TargetType = typeof(DashboardDetail1) };

    // Adding menu items to menuList
    menuList.Add(page1);
    menuList.Add(page2);
    menuList.Add(page3);
    menuList.Add(page4);
    menuList.Add(page5);
    menuList.Add(page6);
    menuList.Add(page7);
    menuList.Add(page8);
    menuList.Add(page9);

    // Setting our list to be ItemSource for ListView in MainPage.xaml
    navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;
    //Application.Current.MainPage = new DashboardMaster();
    // NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

}
private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DashBoadCreator creator = new DashBoadCreator();

    var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;
    Type page = item.TargetType;

    creator.Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
    creator.IsPresented = false;
}
```

}

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>


          <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                    WidthRequest="40"
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />

          <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                 FontSize="Medium"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                 TextColor="Black"/>
         <!-- <Label Text="{Binding Description}"
                 FontSize="Small"
                 VerticalOptions="End"/>-->
          <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End">
            <Button Text="Apply" FontSize="10"  TextColor="Green" BorderWidth="1" HorizontalOptions="End" />
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After of some finding I came accorss this discussion

[Missing menu button on MasterDetailPage when assigning App.MainPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004330/missing-menu-button-on-masterdetailpage-when-assigning-app-mainpage)

Using those findings I changed my app.xaml.cs as follows

```
 MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MenuPage());
 MasterDetailTest.App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
```

Now the Master page is always the root page and the hamburger menu works as expected. To anyone else having this problem hope this helps you in some way

Answer (score 1):

set icon for master page to see hamburger icon

**Sample code :**

```
public masterpage()
{
     Icon = "hamburger.png";
}
```

Comment: When you make MasterDetailPage as root page in App.Xaml.cs everything works as expected. In my case I needed user to Login/Register depending on the actions and then Navigate to MasterDetail Page using following code,

Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MenuPage());
  Navigation.PopToRootAsync(true);
This time the Hamburger menu disappears.

Now to add to that if you change your device orientation physically( changed it on emulator and tried it on Android phone with auto-rotate on), it magically appears!!!!!!!!! How can i work around this?

Comment: I had to set the Icon on the content layout that resided in the master page. I also use a navigation page for my detail page as well.

Answer (score 0):

I coded a working´s demo following a few differents tutos, and getting the most important part of them. So, at least for me, it was a simplier demo I can get it.

Check this link out.

[My github working demo](https://github.com/EliasMerabet/Net/tree/master/Xamarin/Cross/NavigationDrawer)

Where Intervection is a random detail page (constructor by parameter).

Let me know aobut any doubt you could have.

Cheers mate. Merry Christmas.

Comment: I'm working on Xamain forms application so maybe your code won't help me. Meanwhile I've got a solution I think. I'll try it out and post the answer.

Comment: I'll try and let you know. I didn't see the code. The naming convention threw me off a little bit.

Comment: Dont worry. Try it and let me know any doubt. I tested it doing a Master-Detail menu in my own cross app. Master page link with a several detail pages, all of them define for a single page and differentiated by the paramenter which I call the constructor of this single page. If you think my efford deserve it, please rate my answer. Cheers mate.